# RuntimeException: Unclosed single quote in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just download the last Android Studio and create a single project to start learning and I have this error displaying a few times in my Event Log

[image]

**RuntimeException: Unclosed '**

Could someone help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That appears to be the IDE complaining about unmatched single quotes within itself (rather than the program you are building).  If it's not a known issue there may not be much you can do but report it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, It's annoying me for a very long time. Especially, when I want to read some information in **Status Bar**, but instead this I see "*RuntimeException: Unclosed '* " here every time.

[image]

But You can disable this notification:

1. Go to **Event Log** (1) and then **Edit notification settings** (2)

[image]

2. Uncheck **IDE Fatal Errors** log and choose **No popup**

[image]

Of course, this exception still remains and I didn't find the answer why it happens, but now only a small red sign reminds me of it)

[image]

Hope, it was helpful for you)