# Android studio error RuntimeException: Unclosed ': Unclosed '

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I just downloaded the Android Studio BETA 0.8.9 and create a new project, so without touching anything after the build the event log kepp displaying this error.

RuntimeException: Unclosed ': Unclosed '

and here´s the trace

```
Unclosed ': Unclosed '
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unclosed '
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.readTill(CSSParser.java:674)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.nextToken(CSSParser.java:478)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.parseIdentifiers(CSSParser.java:374)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.parseDeclaration(CSSParser.java:357)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.parseDeclarationBlock(CSSParser.java:325)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.parseRuleSet(CSSParser.java:272)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.getNextStatement(CSSParser.java:178)
    at javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser.parse(CSSParser.java:153)
    at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet$CssParser.parse(StyleSheet.java:3187)
    at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addRule(StyleSheet.java:307)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument$HTMLReader.addCSSRules(HTMLDocument.java:3807)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument$HTMLReader$HeadAction.end(HTMLDocument.java:2944)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument$HTMLReader.handleEndTag(HTMLDocument.java:2682)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.handleEndTag(DocumentParser.java:240)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:2263)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.parse(DocumentParser.java:122)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator.parse(ParserDelegator.java:101)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.read(HTMLEditorKit.java:262)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1415)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeTooltipManager.initPane(IdeTooltipManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.hint.LineTooltipRenderer.show(LineTooltipRenderer.java:84)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.hint.TooltipController.showTooltip(TooltipController.java:139)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.hint.TooltipController.showTooltipByMouseMove(TooltipController.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorGutterComponentImpl.mouseMoved(EditorGutterComponentImpl.java:1146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseMotionListener.mouseMoved(EditorImpl.java:5990)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:330)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3338)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6274)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4505)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: That is a bug in the IDE itself. Try to install Android Studio 0.8.11 (available in the Canary Channel) and see if it was already fixed.

Comment: watch [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253393/runtimeexception-unclosed-single-quote-in-android-studio/29720735#29720735)